# Project Euler #13 efficiency

Tags: c#, project-euler, programming-challenge

Okay, so I finally tackled [#13 from Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net/problem=13). I'm said to announce it took me almost 2 hours to come up with this solution, after about an hour of thinking on how to do it.

Here's what I did:

```
private void Euler13()
{
    // store 50 digit numbers into a 100 by 50 array
    int[,] superMegaInt = { {3,7,1,0,7,2,8,7,5,3,3,9,0,2,1,0,2,7,9,8,7,9,7,9,9,8,2,2,0,8,3,7,5,9,0,2,4,6,5,1,0,1,3,5,7,4,0,2,5,0},
                            {4,6,3,7,6,9,3,7,6,7,7,4,9,0,0,0,9,7,1,2,6,4,8,1,2,4,8,9,6,9,7,0,0,7,8,0,5,0,4,1,7,0,1,8,2,6,0,5,3,8},
                            {7,4,3,2,4,9,8,6,1,9,9,5,2,4,7,4,1,0,5,9,4,7,4,2,3,3,3,0,9,5,1,3,0,5,8,1,2,3,7,2,6,6,1,7,3,0,9,6,2,9},
                            {9,1,9,4,2,2,1,3,3,6,3,5,7,4,1,6,1,5,7,2,5,2,2,4,3,0,5,6,3,3,0,1,8,1,1,0,7,2,4,0,6,1,5,4,9,0,8,2,5,0},
                            {2,3,0,6,7,5,8,8,2,0,7,5,3,9,3,4,6,1,7,1,1,7,1,9,8,0,3,1,0,4,2,1,0,4,7,5,1,3,7,7,8,0,6,3,2,4,6,6,7,6},
                            {8,9,2,6,1,6,7,0,6,9,6,6,2,3,6,3,3,8,2,0,1,3,6,3,7,8,4,1,8,3,8,3,6,8,4,1,7,8,7,3,4,3,6,1,7,2,6,7,5,7},
                            {2,8,1,1,2,8,7,9,8,1,2,8,4,9,9,7,9,4,0,8,0,6,5,4,8,1,9,3,1,5,9,2,6,2,1,6,9,1,2,7,5,8,8,9,8,3,2,7,3,8},
                            {4,4,2,7,4,2,2,8,9,1,7,4,3,2,5,2,0,3,2,1,9,2,3,5,8,9,4,2,2,8,7,6,7,9,6,4,8,7,6,7,0,2,7,2,1,8,9,3,1,8},
                            {4,7,4,5,1,4,4,5,7,3,6,0,0,1,3,0,6,4,3,9,0,9,1,1,6,7,2,1,6,8,5,6,8,4,4,5,8,8,7,1,1,6,0,3,1,5,3,2,7,6},
                            {7,0,3,8,6,4,8,6,1,0,5,8,4,3,0,2,5,4,3,9,9,3,9,6,1,9,8,2,8,9,1,7,5,9,3,6,6,5,6,8,6,7,5,7,9,3,4,9,5,1},
                            {6,2,1,7,6,4,5,7,1,4,1,8,5,6,5,6,0,6,2,9,5,0,2,1,5,7,2,2,3,1,9,6,5,8,6,7,5,5,0,7,9,3,2,4,1,9,3,3,3,1},
                            {6,4,9,0,6,3,5,2,4,6,2,7,4,1,9,0,4,9,2,9,1,0,1,4,3,2,4,4,5,8,1,3,8,2,2,6,6,3,3,4,7,9,4,4,7,5,8,1,7,8},
                            {9,2,5,7,5,8,6,7,7,1,8,3,3,7,2,1,7,6,6,1,9,6,3,7,5,1,5,9,0,5,7,9,2,3,9,7,2,8,2,4,5,5,9,8,8,3,8,4,0,7},
                            {5,8,2,0,3,5,6,5,3,2,5,3,5,9,3,9,9,0,0,8,4,0,2,6,3,3,5,6,8,9,4,8,8,3,0,1,8,9,4,5,8,6,2,8,2,2,7,8,2,8},
                            {8,0,1,8,1,1,9,9,3,8,4,8,2,6,2,8,2,0,1,4,2,7,8,1,9,4,1,3,9,9,4,0,5,6,7,5,8,7,1,5,1,1,7,0,0,9,4,3,9,0},
                            {3,5,3,9,8,6,6,4,3,7,2,8,2,7,1,1,2,6,5,3,8,2,9,9,8,7,2,4,0,7,8,4,4,7,3,0,5,3,1,9,0,1,0,4,2,9,3,5,8,6},
                            {8,6,5,1,5,5,0,6,0,0,6,2,9,5,8,6,4,8,6,1,5,3,2,0,7,5,2,7,3,3,7,1,9,5,9,1,9,1,4,2,0,5,1,7,2,5,5,8,2,9},
                            {7,1,6,9,3,8,8,8,7,0,7,7,1,5,4,6,6,4,9,9,1,1,5,5,9,3,4,8,7,6,0,3,5,3,2,9,2,1,7,1,4,9,7,0,0,5,6,9,3,8},
                            {5,4,3,7,0,0,7,0,5,7,6,8,2,6,6,8,4,6,2,4,6,2,1,4,9,5,6,5,0,0,7,6,4,7,1,7,8,7,2,9,4,4,3,8,3,7,7,6,0,4},
                            {5,3,2,8,2,6,5,4,1,0,8,7,5,6,8,2,8,4,4,3,1,9,1,1,9,0,6,3,4,6,9,4,0,3,7,8,5,5,2,1,7,7,7,9,2,9,5,1,4,5},
                            {3,6,1,2,3,2,7,2,5,2,5,0,0,0,2,9,6,0,7,1,0,7,5,0,8,2,5,6,3,8,1,5,6,5,6,7,1,0,8,8,5,2,5,8,3,5,0,7,2,1},
                            {4,5,8,7,6,5,7,6,1,7,2,4,1,0,9,7,6,4,4,7,3,3,9,1,1,0,6,0,7,2,1,8,2,6,5,2,3,6,8,7,7,2,2,3,6,3,6,0,4,5},
                            {1,7,4,2,3,7,0,6,9,0,5,8,5,1,8,6,0,6,6,0,4,4,8,2,0,7,6,2,1,2,0,9,8,1,3,2,8,7,8,6,0,7,3,3,9,6,9,4,1,2},
                            {8,1,1,4,2,6,6,0,4,1,8,0,8,6,8,3,0,6,1,9,3,2,8,4,6,0,8,1,1,1,9,1,0,6,1,5,5,6,9,4,0,5,1,2,6,8,9,6,9,2},
                            {5,1,9,3,4,3,2,5,4,5,1,7,2,8,3,8,8,6,4,1,9,1,8,0,4,7,0,4,9,2,9,3,2,1,5,0,5,8,6,4,2,5,6,3,0,4,9,4,8,3},
                            {6,2,4,6,7,2,2,1,6,4,8,4,3,5,0,7,6,2,0,1,7,2,7,9,1,8,0,3,9,9,4,4,6,9,3,0,0,4,7,3,2,9,5,6,3,4,0,6,9,1},
                            {1,5,7,3,2,4,4,4,3,8,6,9,0,8,1,2,5,7,9,4,5,1,4,0,8,9,0,5,7,7,0,6,2,2,9,4,2,9,1,9,7,1,0,7,9,2,8,2,0,9},
                            {5,5,0,3,7,6,8,7,5,2,5,6,7,8,7,7,3,0,9,1,8,6,2,5,4,0,7,4,4,9,6,9,8,4,4,5,0,8,3,3,0,3,9,3,6,8,2,1,2,6},
                            {1,8,3,3,6,3,8,4,8,2,5,3,3,0,1,5,4,6,8,6,1,9,6,1,2,4,3,4,8,7,6,7,6,8,1,2,9,7,5,3,4,3,7,5,9,4,6,5,1,5},
                            {8,0,3,8,6,2,8,7,5,9,2,8,7,8,4,9,0,2,0,1,5,2,1,6,8,5,5,5,4,8,2,8,7,1,7,2,0,1,2,1,9,2,5,7,7,6,6,9,5,4},
                            {7,8,1,8,2,8,3,3,7,5,7,9,9,3,1,0,3,6,1,4,7,4,0,3,5,6,8,5,6,4,4,9,0,9,5,5,2,7,0,9,7,8,6,4,7,9,7,5,8,1},
                            {1,6,7,2,6,3,2,0,1,0,0,4,3,6,8,9,7,8,4,2,5,5,3,5,3,9,9,2,0,9,3,1,8,3,7,4,4,1,4,9,7,8,0,6,8,6,0,9,8,4},
                            {4,8,4,0,3,0,9,8,1,2,9,0,7,7,7,9,1,7,9,9,0,8,8,2,1,8,7,9,5,3,2,7,3,6,4,4,7,5,6,7,5,5,9,0,8,4,8,0,3,0},
                            {8,7,0,8,6,9,8,7,5,5,1,3,9,2,7,1,1,8,5,4,5,1,7,0,7,8,5,4,4,1,6,1,8,5,2,4,2,4,3,2,0,6,9,3,1,5,0,3,3,2},
                            {5,9,9,5,9,4,0,6,8,9,5,7,5,6,5,3,6,7,8,2,1,0,7,0,7,4,9,2,6,9,6,6,5,3,7,6,7,6,3,2,6,2,3,5,4,4,7,2,1,0},
                            {6,9,7,9,3,9,5,0,6,7,9,6,5,2,6,9,4,7,4,2,5,9,7,7,0,9,7,3,9,1,6,6,6,9,3,7,6,3,0,4,2,6,3,3,9,8,7,0,8,5},
                            {4,1,0,5,2,6,8,4,7,0,8,2,9,9,0,8,5,2,1,1,3,9,9,4,2,7,3,6,5,7,3,4,1,1,6,1,8,2,7,6,0,3,1,5,0,0,1,2,7,1},
                            {6,5,3,7,8,6,0,7,3,6,1,5,0,1,0,8,0,8,5,7,0,0,9,1,4,9,9,3,9,5,1,2,5,5,7,0,2,8,1,9,8,7,4,6,0,0,4,3,7,5},
                            {3,5,8,2,9,0,3,5,3,1,7,4,3,4,7,1,7,3,2,6,9,3,2,1,2,3,5,7,8,1,5,4,9,8,2,6,2,9,7,4,2,5,5,2,7,3,7,3,0,7},
                            {9,4,9,5,3,7,5,9,7,6,5,1,0,5,3,0,5,9,4,6,9,6,6,0,6,7,6,8,3,1,5,6,5,7,4,3,7,7,1,6,7,4,0,1,8,7,5,2,7,5},
                            {8,8,9,0,2,8,0,2,5,7,1,7,3,3,2,2,9,6,1,9,1,7,6,6,6,8,7,1,3,8,1,9,9,3,1,8,1,1,0,4,8,7,7,0,1,9,0,2,7,1},
                            {2,5,2,6,7,6,8,0,2,7,6,0,7,8,0,0,3,0,1,3,6,7,8,6,8,0,9,9,2,5,2,5,4,6,3,4,0,1,0,6,1,6,3,2,8,6,6,5,2,6},
                            {3,6,2,7,0,2,1,8,5,4,0,4,9,7,7,0,5,5,8,5,6,2,9,9,4,6,5,8,0,6,3,6,2,3,7,9,9,3,1,4,0,7,4,6,2,5,5,9,6,2},
                            {2,4,0,7,4,4,8,6,9,0,8,2,3,1,1,7,4,9,7,7,7,9,2,3,6,5,4,6,6,2,5,7,2,4,6,9,2,3,3,2,2,8,1,0,9,1,7,1,4,1},
                            {9,1,4,3,0,2,8,8,1,9,7,1,0,3,2,8,8,5,9,7,8,0,6,6,6,9,7,6,0,8,9,2,9,3,8,6,3,8,2,8,5,0,2,5,3,3,3,4,0,3},
                            {3,4,4,1,3,0,6,5,5,7,8,0,1,6,1,2,7,8,1,5,9,2,1,8,1,5,0,0,5,5,6,1,8,6,8,8,3,6,4,6,8,4,2,0,0,9,0,4,7,0},
                            {2,3,0,5,3,0,8,1,1,7,2,8,1,6,4,3,0,4,8,7,6,2,3,7,9,1,9,6,9,8,4,2,4,8,7,2,5,5,0,3,6,6,3,8,7,8,4,5,8,3},
                            {1,1,4,8,7,6,9,6,9,3,2,1,5,4,9,0,2,8,1,0,4,2,4,0,2,0,1,3,8,3,3,5,1,2,4,4,6,2,1,8,1,4,4,1,7,7,3,4,7,0},
                            {6,3,7,8,3,2,9,9,4,9,0,6,3,6,2,5,9,6,6,6,4,9,8,5,8,7,6,1,8,2,2,1,2,2,5,2,2,5,5,1,2,4,8,6,7,6,4,5,3,3},
                            {6,7,7,2,0,1,8,6,9,7,1,6,9,8,5,4,4,3,1,2,4,1,9,5,7,2,4,0,9,9,1,3,9,5,9,0,0,8,9,5,2,3,1,0,0,5,8,8,2,2},
                            {9,5,5,4,8,2,5,5,3,0,0,2,6,3,5,2,0,7,8,1,5,3,2,2,9,6,7,9,6,2,4,9,4,8,1,6,4,1,9,5,3,8,6,8,2,1,8,7,7,4},
                            {7,6,0,8,5,3,2,7,1,3,2,2,8,5,7,2,3,1,1,0,4,2,4,8,0,3,4,5,6,1,2,4,8,6,7,6,9,7,0,6,4,5,0,7,9,9,5,2,3,6},
                            {3,7,7,7,4,2,4,2,5,3,5,4,1,1,2,9,1,6,8,4,2,7,6,8,6,5,5,3,8,9,2,6,2,0,5,0,2,4,9,1,0,3,2,6,5,7,2,9,6,7},
                            {2,3,7,0,1,9,1,3,2,7,5,7,2,5,6,7,5,2,8,5,6,5,3,2,4,8,2,5,8,2,6,5,4,6,3,0,9,2,2,0,7,0,5,8,5,9,6,5,2,2},
                            {2,9,7,9,8,8,6,0,2,7,2,2,5,8,3,3,1,9,1,3,1,2,6,3,7,5,1,4,7,3,4,1,9,9,4,8,8,9,5,3,4,7,6,5,7,4,5,5,0,1},
                            {1,8,4,9,5,7,0,1,4,5,4,8,7,9,2,8,8,9,8,4,8,5,6,8,2,7,7,2,6,0,7,7,7,1,3,7,2,1,4,0,3,7,9,8,8,7,9,7,1,5},
                            {3,8,2,9,8,2,0,3,7,8,3,0,3,1,4,7,3,5,2,7,7,2,1,5,8,0,3,4,8,1,4,4,5,1,3,4,9,1,3,7,3,2,2,6,6,5,1,3,8,1},
                            {3,4,8,2,9,5,4,3,8,2,9,1,9,9,9,1,8,1,8,0,2,7,8,9,1,6,5,2,2,4,3,1,0,2,7,3,9,2,2,5,1,1,2,2,8,6,9,5,3,9},
                            {4,0,9,5,7,9,5,3,0,6,6,4,0,5,2,3,2,6,3,2,5,3,8,0,4,4,1,0,0,0,5,9,6,5,4,9,3,9,1,5,9,8,7,9,5,9,3,6,3,5},
                            {2,9,7,4,6,1,5,2,1,8,5,5,0,2,3,7,1,3,0,7,6,4,2,2,5,5,1,2,1,1,8,3,6,9,3,8,0,3,5,8,0,3,8,8,5,8,4,9,0,3},
                            {4,1,6,9,8,1,1,6,2,2,2,0,7,2,9,7,7,1,8,6,1,5,8,2,3,6,6,7,8,4,2,4,6,8,9,1,5,7,9,9,3,5,3,2,9,6,1,9,2,2},
                            {6,2,4,6,7,9,5,7,1,9,4,4,0,1,2,6,9,0,4,3,8,7,7,1,0,7,2,7,5,0,4,8,1,0,2,3,9,0,8,9,5,5,2,3,5,9,7,4,5,7},
                            {2,3,1,8,9,7,0,6,7,7,2,5,4,7,9,1,5,0,6,1,5,0,5,5,0,4,9,5,3,9,2,2,9,7,9,5,3,0,9,0,1,1,2,9,9,6,7,5,1,9},
                            {8,6,1,8,8,0,8,8,2,2,5,8,7,5,3,1,4,5,2,9,5,8,4,0,9,9,2,5,1,2,0,3,8,2,9,0,0,9,4,0,7,7,7,0,7,7,5,6,7,2},
                            {1,1,3,0,6,7,3,9,7,0,8,3,0,4,7,2,4,4,8,3,8,1,6,5,3,3,8,7,3,5,0,2,3,4,0,8,4,5,6,4,7,0,5,8,0,7,7,3,0,8},
                            {8,2,9,5,9,1,7,4,7,6,7,1,4,0,3,6,3,1,9,8,0,0,8,1,8,7,1,2,9,0,1,1,8,7,5,4,9,1,3,1,0,5,4,7,1,2,6,5,8,1},
                            {9,7,6,2,3,3,3,1,0,4,4,8,1,8,3,8,6,2,6,9,5,1,5,4,5,6,3,3,4,9,2,6,3,6,6,5,7,2,8,9,7,5,6,3,4,0,0,5,0,0},
                            {4,2,8,4,6,2,8,0,1,8,3,5,1,7,0,7,0,5,2,7,8,3,1,8,3,9,4,2,5,8,8,2,1,4,5,5,2,1,2,2,7,2,5,1,2,5,0,3,2,7},
                            {5,5,1,2,1,6,0,3,5,4,6,9,8,1,2,0,0,5,8,1,7,6,2,1,6,5,2,1,2,8,2,7,6,5,2,7,5,1,6,9,1,2,9,6,8,9,7,7,8,9},
                            {3,2,2,3,8,1,9,5,7,3,4,3,2,9,3,3,9,9,4,6,4,3,7,5,0,1,9,0,7,8,3,6,9,4,5,7,6,5,8,8,3,3,5,2,3,9,9,8,8,6},
                            {7,5,5,0,6,1,6,4,9,6,5,1,8,4,7,7,5,1,8,0,7,3,8,1,6,8,8,3,7,8,6,1,0,9,1,5,2,7,3,5,7,9,2,9,7,0,1,3,3,7},
                            {6,2,1,7,7,8,4,2,7,5,2,1,9,2,6,2,3,4,0,1,9,4,2,3,9,9,6,3,9,1,6,8,0,4,4,9,8,3,9,9,3,1,7,3,3,1,2,7,3,1},
                            {3,2,9,2,4,1,8,5,7,0,7,1,4,7,3,4,9,5,6,6,9,1,6,6,7,4,6,8,7,6,3,4,6,6,0,9,1,5,0,3,5,9,1,4,6,7,7,5,0,4},
                            {9,9,5,1,8,6,7,1,4,3,0,2,3,5,2,1,9,6,2,8,8,9,4,8,9,0,1,0,2,4,2,3,3,2,5,1,1,6,9,1,3,6,1,9,6,2,6,6,2,2},
                            {7,3,2,6,7,4,6,0,8,0,0,5,9,1,5,4,7,4,7,1,8,3,0,7,9,8,3,9,2,8,6,8,5,3,5,2,0,6,9,4,6,9,4,4,5,4,0,7,2,4},
                            {7,6,8,4,1,8,2,2,5,2,4,6,7,4,4,1,7,1,6,1,5,1,4,0,3,6,4,2,7,9,8,2,2,7,3,3,4,8,0,5,5,5,5,6,2,1,4,8,1,8},
                            {9,7,1,4,2,6,1,7,9,1,0,3,4,2,5,9,8,6,4,7,2,0,4,5,1,6,8,9,3,9,8,9,4,2,2,1,7,9,8,2,6,0,8,8,0,7,6,8,5,2},
                            {8,7,7,8,3,6,4,6,1,8,2,7,9,9,3,4,6,3,1,3,7,6,7,7,5,4,3,0,7,8,0,9,3,6,3,3,3,3,0,1,8,9,8,2,6,4,2,0,9,0},
                            {1,0,8,4,8,8,0,2,5,2,1,6,7,4,6,7,0,8,8,3,2,1,5,1,2,0,1,8,5,8,8,3,5,4,3,2,2,3,8,1,2,8,7,6,9,5,2,7,8,6},
                            {7,1,3,2,9,6,1,2,4,7,4,7,8,2,4,6,4,5,3,8,6,3,6,9,9,3,0,0,9,0,4,9,3,1,0,3,6,3,6,1,9,7,6,3,8,7,8,0,3,9},
                            {6,2,1,8,4,0,7,3,5,7,2,3,9,9,7,9,4,2,2,3,4,0,6,2,3,5,3,9,3,8,0,8,3,3,9,6,5,1,3,2,7,4,0,8,0,1,1,1,1,6},
                            {6,6,6,2,7,8,9,1,9,8,1,4,8,8,0,8,7,7,9,7,9,4,1,8,7,6,8,7,6,1,4,4,2,3,0,0,3,0,9,8,4,4,9,0,8,5,1,4,1,1},
                            {6,0,6,6,1,8,2,6,2,9,3,6,8,2,8,3,6,7,6,4,7,4,4,7,7,9,2,3,9,1,8,0,3,3,5,1,1,0,9,8,9,0,6,9,7,9,0,7,1,4},
                            {8,5,7,8,6,9,4,4,0,8,9,5,5,2,9,9,0,6,5,3,6,4,0,4,4,7,4,2,5,5,7,6,0,8,3,6,5,9,9,7,6,6,4,5,7,9,5,0,9,6},
                            {6,6,0,2,4,3,9,6,4,0,9,9,0,5,3,8,9,6,0,7,1,2,0,1,9,8,2,1,9,9,7,6,0,4,7,5,9,9,4,9,0,1,9,7,2,3,0,2,9,7},
                            {6,4,9,1,3,9,8,2,6,8,0,0,3,2,9,7,3,1,5,6,0,3,7,1,2,0,0,4,1,3,7,7,9,0,3,7,8,5,5,6,6,0,8,5,0,8,9,2,5,2},
                            {1,6,7,3,0,9,3,9,3,1,9,8,7,2,7,5,0,2,7,5,4,6,8,9,0,6,9,0,3,7,0,7,5,3,9,4,1,3,0,4,2,6,5,2,3,1,5,0,1,1},
                            {9,4,8,0,9,3,7,7,2,4,5,0,4,8,7,9,5,1,5,0,9,5,4,1,0,0,9,2,1,6,4,5,8,6,3,7,5,4,7,1,0,5,9,8,4,3,6,7,9,1},
                            {7,8,6,3,9,1,6,7,0,2,1,1,8,7,4,9,2,4,3,1,9,9,5,7,0,0,6,4,1,9,1,7,9,6,9,7,7,7,5,9,9,0,2,8,3,0,0,6,9,9},
                            {1,5,3,6,8,7,1,3,7,1,1,9,3,6,6,1,4,9,5,2,8,1,1,3,0,5,8,7,6,3,8,0,2,7,8,4,1,0,7,5,4,4,4,9,7,3,3,0,7,8},
                            {4,0,7,8,9,9,2,3,1,1,5,5,3,5,5,6,2,5,6,1,1,4,2,3,2,2,4,2,3,2,5,5,0,3,3,6,8,5,4,4,2,4,8,8,9,1,7,3,5,3},
                            {4,4,8,8,9,9,1,1,5,0,1,4,4,0,6,4,8,0,2,0,3,6,9,0,6,8,0,6,3,9,6,0,6,7,2,3,2,2,1,9,3,2,0,4,1,4,9,5,3,5},
                            {4,1,5,0,3,1,2,8,8,8,0,3,3,9,5,3,6,0,5,3,2,9,9,3,4,0,3,6,8,0,0,6,9,7,7,7,1,0,6,5,0,5,6,6,6,3,1,9,5,4},
                            {8,1,2,3,4,8,8,0,6,7,3,2,1,0,1,4,6,7,3,9,0,5,8,5,6,8,5,5,7,9,3,4,5,8,1,4,0,3,6,2,7,8,2,2,7,0,3,2,8,0},
                            {8,2,6,1,6,5,7,0,7,7,3,9,4,8,3,2,7,5,9,2,2,3,2,8,4,5,9,4,1,7,0,6,5,2,5,0,9,4,5,1,2,3,2,5,2,3,0,6,0,8},
                            {2,2,9,1,8,8,0,2,0,5,8,7,7,7,3,1,9,7,1,9,8,3,9,4,5,0,1,8,0,8,8,8,0,7,2,4,2,9,6,6,1,9,8,0,8,1,1,1,9,7},
                            {7,7,1,5,8,5,4,2,5,0,2,0,1,6,5,4,5,0,9,0,4,1,3,2,4,5,8,0,9,7,8,6,8,8,2,7,7,8,9,4,8,7,2,1,8,5,9,6,1,7},
                            {7,2,1,0,7,8,3,8,4,3,5,0,6,9,1,8,6,1,5,5,4,3,5,6,6,2,8,8,4,0,6,2,2,5,7,4,7,3,6,9,2,2,8,4,5,0,9,5,1,6},
                            {2,0,8,4,9,6,0,3,9,8,0,1,3,4,0,0,1,7,2,3,9,3,0,6,7,1,6,6,6,8,2,3,5,5,5,2,4,5,2,5,2,8,0,4,6,0,9,7,2,2},
                            {5,3,5,0,3,5,3,4,2,2,6,4,7,2,5,2,4,2,5,0,8,7,4,0,5,4,0,7,5,5,9,1,7,8,9,7,8,1,2,6,4,3,3,0,3,3,1,6,9,0} };

    label1.Text = AddTheInts(superMegaInt);
}

private string AddTheInts(int[,] ints)
{
    var result = "";
    var total = 0;

   // the idea is to loop through the last element of each array, and add them together, carry the reminder on to the next to the last. repeat till done
   for(var j = 49; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            total += ints[i,j];
        }

        if (j == 0)
        {
            result = total.ToString() + result;
        }
        else
        {
            result = (total % 10).ToString() + result;

            total = total - (total % 10);
            total /= 10;
        }
    }
    return result.Substring(0,10);
}
```

Now, this works, and I got the correct answer. But I'm 1000% certain there has to be a better way of doing this. And I feel that even if this hadn't taken me 2 hours, if I'd have done this on an interview test, I'd have been laughed at. So, how else should I have accomplished this?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2008/12/19/project-euler-13.aspx or maybe http://www.geekality.net/2009/10/04/project-euler-problem-13/ or even http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-13/

Comment: i hope you didn't write down those arrays manually

Comment: @JustinL. Not completely.

Comment: The best refactoring here is to take another language: `str.scan(/\d{50}/).map(&:to_i).inject(:+).to_s[0...10]`

Comment: If you have already saved the problem you can create an account at projec euler and submit your solution. Then you are authorized to view the thread for this problem in the restricted project euler forum (the links can be found at tje bottom of the problem 13, but only if you have submitted a valid solution) You acn check the solutions of the other users. Especially the second pos of user rayfil may be interresting if you want to improve  your solution: https://projecteuler.net/thread=13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't hard code the input. Instead, make your program read and parse a text file containing the input, or something like that.
2. If you can use `BigInteger` to represent the numbers, use it. If you think that would be cheating, write your own `BigInteger` that supports `Parse()`, `ToString()` and `+`.
3. You can then use LINQ to sum the numbers. `Sum()` doesn't work for `BigInteger`s, but you can use `Aggregate()`.

With that, your code would look something like this:

```
string result =
    File.ReadAllLines("euler13.txt")
        .Select(BigInteger.Parse)
        .Aggregate((i1, i2) => i1 + i2)
        .ToString()
        .Substring(0, 10);
```

This is basically the same code as the one from Nakilon's comment, only in a language that supports names with more than 4 characters :-)